# Laravel (Eloquent) Ways of Updating DB

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am following some laravel tutorials

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->email = 'john@foo.com';

$user->save();
```

But let's say I did

```
$user = User::where('name', '=', 'jeff')->first;
```

Would I then be able to update the variable by simply doing?

```
$user->name = 'josh'; 
$user->save;
```

Would this work? Or must I perform the find command?

Thanks!

Comment: That should be fine, though im not a laravel user, so your best option would be to just try it and find out for your self!

Comment: That's right, but don't forget: `()` after save and after first method. Correct: `$user->save()`

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the tip! You guys both saved me. I tried in tinker it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many way to update your model. You can use `save()` method only on [Collection](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#available-methods).

### 1. Define a collection

```
$user = User::where('name', '=', 'jeff')->first();
```

### 2. Update attributes

```
$user->email = "test@test.com";
$user->name = "Test User";
```

### 3. Use save() method

```
$user->save();
```

Comment: Thanks. You're the best!

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct, if it helped for you.:)

Comment: Yes, of course. I just had to wait a minute for some reason. :)